# Removing dataframe from list with no data RStudio

Tags: r, list, dataframe, rstudio

I do most of my projects with lists downloading information from the web. Sometimes when I download 100 different sets of data the website does not give me data for a few of them.

You can tell it has no data because it says.

A data.frame with 0 rows and 7 colums.

A good dataframe says something like this.

A data.Frame with 245345 rows and 7 colums.

My script does not like no data in the list. It stops my loop in that spot.

Thank you in advance.

```
 #Pulls all the active USGS gages for the URL's 
    GageList <- CDEC
    gage <- c(as.character(GageList$GAGE_ID))
    duration <- c(as.character(GageList$DURATION_CODE))
    number <- c(as.character(GageList$SENSOR_CODE))
    View(GageList)

    #CDEC URL
    urls <- sprintf(final=list()
    TOTALERRORS =list()

    #Pulls all the active USGS gages for the URL's 
    GageList <- CDEC
    gage <- c(as.character(GageList$GAGE_ID))
    duration <- c(as.character(GageList$DURATION_CODE))
    number <- c(as.character(GageList$SENSOR_CODE))
    View(GageList)

    #CDEC URL
    urls <- sprintf("http://cdec.water.ca.gov/cgi-progs/querySHEF? 
    station_id=%s&dur_code=%s&sensor_num=%s&start_date=10/25/2019", 
    gage,duration,number)
    View(urls)



data <- suppressWarnings(lapply(urls, fread, header=TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 0):

It difficult to answer whithout having an eye on the list. But from your description, here is an example :

```
# first here is a list of data.frame
l = list(data.frame(0,nrow = 2,ncol =5),
         data.frame(0,nrow = 1, ncol=5))
# here i remove the only row of the second data.frame
l[[2]] = l[[2]][-1,]

l
# I set a data.frame identifiying the dim of each data.frame
d2rm = data.frame(n = rep(1:length(l),each = 2),
                  empty =unlist(lapply(l,dim)) == 0)

# I remove from the list the data.frames that have dim of 0 (in col or row)
l[[d2rm[which(d2rm$empty),1]]] = NULL

l
```